# problem IndexError: list index out of range in youtube search

Tags: python

The code gets songs names from spotify playlist and then saves them in file named "songs". Then, line by line it searches youtube by name and gets the url of the songs. It works and gives me a bunch of urls, but after some time it stops and give me this error:

```
url = video['result'][0]['link']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and the songs file has like 200 songs names it stop at 148

```
from os import link
from pytube.streams import Stream
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import spotipy
import json
from pytube import YouTube
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch


cid = ''
secret = ''


auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

username = "Zetona"
playlist = "spotify:playlist:3sQMXSZ9662KzJQJMVfWPI"

results = sp.user_playlist_tracks(username,playlist_id=playlist,)
tracks = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = sp.next(results)
    tracks.extend(results['items'])
x=[]
for item in tracks:
    x.append(
        item['track']['name'] + ' - ' +
        item['track']['artists'][0]['name'] + ' - ' +
        item['track']['album']['name'])

with open('songs','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(x))
    f.close()
print("done")

############## youtube search ###########

with open('songs') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
print(lines)

for line in lines:
    count=+ 1
    videosSearch = VideosSearch(line, limit = 1)
    video = videosSearch.result()
    url = video['result'][0]['link']

    print(url)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Comment: why is it wrong ?

Comment: Because you need to write in full sentences with proper punctuation, so that people can understand you. You also need to ask a clear, specific question: "help me pls" is not good enough. You should also try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code yourself. For example, if `video['result'][0]['link']` does not work, does `video['result'][0]` work? How about `video['result']`? When you try to check those things, what do you learn about the data?

Comment: Most likely it can't find a video for a particular song. Add some code to handle that.

Comment: the problem is that it get me the urls but idk why it stop and give me the error

Comment: im trying now to check if video['result'] work or no its my first time asking here so im kinda noob go easy on me lol

Comment: You could wrap the code in a `try/except` block and inside the except print out some debugging info to see what is causing the error.

Comment: i get same problem when i use video['result']

Comment: this problem 
  File "c:\Users\Mohamed_Zeton\Desktop\spotify app android project\run.py", line 48, in <module>
    url = video['result'][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: i didnt understand you about try/except

Comment: i got it now when i use this     url = video['result'] it works and give me all the songs things and when the last song stop it give this in between the things like this []